Is it possible to deconstruct and have a using declaration in the same statement
I'm trying to do something like this:
using var (dbConnection, dbContext) = GetDbContext();

Which is mixing the using statement for disposing automatically and deconstructing the tuple into two separate values having following method for example:
public static (SqliteConnection, DbContext) GetDbContext()
{
    // Create and return the following objects

    return (dbConnection, dbContext);
}

This doesn't work, I tried a few different variants but without any luck. The best I was able to do was:
var dbInfo = DbContextHelper.GetDbContext();
using var dbConnection = dbInfo.Item1;
using var dbContext = dbInfo.Item2;


I doubt there will ever be syntax for inlining this, because a deconstruction may have any number of IDisposable & non-IDisposable items.

That could be circumvented by a (using var dbConnection, using var dbContext) = GetDbContext(); but that syntax does also not exist. And i never missed something like that. So priority wise i would expect it to never happen.

In this specific example i would even propose to not use the shortcut using var syntax in any way. The lifetime of a dbconnection is mostly connected with a costly resource and should be returned as early as possible and not be waited for until the scope ends.
